# visual studio 2015 c++ Stack around the variable was corrupted run time error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting the following run time error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'sign' was corrupted.
```

When running the following code (`display_utils.h`):

```
    #pragma once

    #include <string>
    using std::string;

    class display_utils
    {
    public:
        void insert_5_lines();
        string fit_int_2(int);
        string fit_int_3(int);
        string disp_ave(double);
    private:
        int dummy;
    };

display_utils.cpp

    #include <iostream>
    using std::cout;

    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>

    #include "display_utils.h"

    void display_utils::insert_5_lines()
    {
        cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";
    }

    string display_utils::fit_int_2(int i0)
    {
        string s0 = "";

        if (i0 < 10)
        {
            s0 = " ";
        }
        return s0;
    }

    string display_utils::fit_int_3(int i0)
    {
        string s0 = "";

        if (i0 < 10)
        {
            s0 = "  ";
        }
        else if (i0 < 100)
        {
            s0 = " ";
        }
        return s0;
    }

    string display_utils::disp_ave(double ave)
    {
        int err;
        int dec;
        int sign;
        char buf[8] = "";

        err = _fcvt_s(buf, 32, ave, 4, &dec, &sign);   // <- error occurs here

    //  cout << "\n";
    //  cout << "buf = " << buf << " ";
    //  cout << "err = " << err << " ";
    //  cout << "dec = " << dec << " ";
    //  cout << "sign = " << sign << " \n";

        string a0(buf);

        return a0;
    }
```

Note that when I press "*continue*" (in the debugger) the program appears to work fine, as in it does what I'm expecting.  When I added the debug code to display the double to string function parameters, they all looked fine (the commented out code in the `disp_ave` function).

Answer (score 1):

The buffer is 8 bytes, but the call to `_fcvt_s` says it's 32 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking [`_fcvt_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty40w2f3.aspx) with the following: a `char[8]` but passing in a size of `32`. Note that there's a templated version where you don't need to pass in the bytes, so you could simply change your code to:

```
err = _fcvt_s(buf, ave, 4, &dec, &sign);
```

Which will invoke the templated version.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The templated version works fine, no run time errors.